# Paypal cURL request - ERRORCODE0=81002

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to do an NVP pay request via cURL to the Paypal servers, but i always end up getting ERRORCODE0=81002, which basically means there's something wrong with my method.
But I just cant seem to find the problem:

```
//The request parameters
 $request_params = array(
    'METHOD' => 'PAY',
    'VERSION' => '85.0',
    'USER' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'PWD' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'SIGNATURE' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'RETURNURL' => 'https://localhost',
    'CANCELURL' => 'https://localhost'
 );
 $endpoint = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?';

 //Building the NVP string
 $request = http_build_query($request_params);

 //cURL settings
 $curl_options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
 );

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options);

 $response = curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where did you get this sample from?

I never saw the value "PAY" for "METHOD"
These need to be valid paypal actions. For example most recently I used DoDirectPayment (and *I think* that is the most used method for payments with paypal pro)

all the operations are available in this table on their site: http://rvyu.com/rcuu

Update: so the main question is: what do you want to do? because I don't think you are making a payment since you are not sending some basic fields (like the amount or card number); after that look for the value that matches the action you need to take

Comment: 'Pay' is an Adaptive Payments API method, but this is not available on https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp -- as you said, you'd need to use a proper METHOD, such as DoDirectPayment, SetExpressCheckout, GetBalance, et cetera.